# ExtJS4: How to show validation error message next to textbox, combobox etc

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I need to implement validation messages that appear right next to invalid field. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this is straight out of examples. you'll be better served going through them.

Comment: @DmitryB, thanks for reply. Can you provide me some examples? Please read my comment to JohnnyHK below.

Comment: I take my comment back. The only way to display the full error message out of the box is with 'under' msgTarget - see Phone field in this example: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/form/fieldcontainer.html  @Jomet below mentioned the element ID witch is a bit more work but that's what you'll have to do.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`msgTarget: 'side'`  will Add an error icon to the right of the field, displaying the message in a popup on hover only.

if you read the documentation carefully, one more option is there for msgTarget http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-msgTarget

**[element id] Add the error message directly to the innerHTML of the specified element.**
you have to add a "td" to the right side of the control dynamically with the id. then if you specify `msgTarget: 'element id'`  it will work.

Answer (score 10):

The `msgTarget: 'elementId'` can work, but it seem very limited, particularly when you want multiple instances of one reusable ExtJs component (and therefor multiple instances of the same msgTarget element). For example I have an MDI style editor where you can open multiple editors of one type in a tab interface. It also doesn't seem to work with `itemId` or recognize DOM/container hierarchy.

I therefor prefer to turn off the default handling if I don't want exactly one of the built in  message display options by setting `msgTarget: none` and then performing my own message display by handling the `fielderrorchange` event which is designed for exactly this scenario. In this case I can now respect hierarchy of my forms even with multiple instances of the same editor form as I can select the error display element relative to the editor.

Here's how I do it:

```
{
    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
    fieldLabel: 'My Field Label',
    layout: 'hbox',   // this will be container with 2 elements: the editor & the error
    items: [{
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        itemId: 'myDataFieldName',
        name: 'myDataFieldName',
        width: 150,
        msgTarget: 'none',  // don't use the default built in error message display
        validator: function (value) {
            return 'This is my custom validation message. All real validation logic removed for example clarity.';
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'label',
        itemId: 'errorBox', // This ID lets me find the display element relative to the editor above
        cls: 'errorBox'     // This class lets me customize the appearance of the error element in CSS
    }],
    listeners: {
        'fielderrorchange': function (container, field, error, eOpts) {
            var errUI = container.down('#errorBox');
            if (error) {
                // show error element, don't esape any HTML formatting provided
                errUI.setText(error, false);
                errUI.show();
            } else {
                // hide error element
                errUI.hide();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

See the [msgTarget](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-msgTarget) config of the control.  `msgTarget: 'side'` would put the validation message to the right of the control.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this option is putting only exclamation icon to the right of the control, but not the message. I need message appeared, not as a tooltip of the icon.

Answer (score 2):

Use msgTarget 'side' for validation in right side and msgTarget 'under' for bottom

```
     items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Name',
                allowBlank: false,
                name: 'name',
                msgTarget: 'side',
                blankText: 'This should not be blank!'
            }]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'msgTarget: [element id]'. You have to write html in order to use element id instead of itemId. The validation function adds a list element under an element that you set as 'msgTarget'.
In case you want to show elements that you want for the validation, you can pass html instead of just a text.

```
{
    xtype: 'container',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            allowBlank: false,
            msgTarget: 'hoge'
            blankText: '<div style="color:red;">validation message</div>', // optional
        },
        {
            xtype: 'box',
            html: '<div id="hoge"></div>' // this id has to be same as msgTarget
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To show the error message **under/side** the input text box, **msgTarget** property will work only in case of you are using the form layout.

To work around this in other than form layout we need to wrap the element in "x-form-field-wrap" class.

you can find more on thread :
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?86900-msgTarget-under-problem