# extjs 4 - How change default message error in field

Tags: extjs, field, extjs4.1

I have a form panel in **http://jsfiddle.net/7CLWy/**
here is my important code

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'First Name',
    allowBlank: false,
    msgTarget: 'under',
    name: 'firstName'
}, {
    xtype: 'datefield',
    allowBlank: false,
    fieldLabel: 'Start date',
    msgTarget: 'under'
}],
```

I want change default message error in field

[image]

How to change that. Thanks

Comment: Did you read the docs?  It's there http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/?mobile=/api/Ext.form.field.Base invalidText

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `blankText` property is the validation message when a field is required, and `invalidText` is the text when the field generically fails validation.  You can add your own custom messages in these properties.  Similarly, if you happened to be doing regex-based validation with the `regex` property, you could use the `regexText` field to provide a custom validation message.

```
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        allowBlank: false,
        msgTarget: 'under',
        name: 'firstName',
        blankText: 'This should not be blank!'
    }, {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        allowBlank: false,
        fieldLabel: 'Start date',
        msgTarget: 'under',
        invalidText: 'This value is not a valid date!'
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Digits followed by A,B,or C',
        msgTarget: 'under',
        name: 'someText',
        regex: /^\d+[ABC]$/,
        regexText: 'This must be a string of digits followed by A, B, or C!'
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

msgTarget: 'side' will Add an error icon to the right of the field, displaying the message in a popup on hover only.

if you read the documentation carefully, one more option is there for msgTarget http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-msgTarget

**[element id] Add the error message directly to the innerHTML of the specified element**. you have to add a "td" to the right side of the control dynamically with the id. then if you specify msgTarget: 'element id' it will work.

reference ->[ExtJS4: How to show validation error message next to textbox, combobox etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870851/extjs4-how-to-show-validation-error-message-next-to-textbox-combobox-etc)

Comment: sorry :( I read but I don't understand well, I try msgTarget: 'myid' and document.getElementById("myid").innerHTML='my msg';. Can you make a example working thanks

Answer (score 0):

we can use validator method and return the custom message.

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Digits followed by A,B,or C',
    msgTarget: 'under',
    name: 'someText',
    validator : function(value){
         var regex= /^\d+[ABC]$/;
         if(!regex.test(value)){
              return "'This must be a string of digits followed by A, B, or C!'"
          }
         return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

To change the default active error message we use setActiveError( msg ).you see the following code.

```
items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        allowBlank: false,
        id:'fn',
        msgTarget: 'under',
        name: 'firstName',

    }, {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        allowBlank: false,
        fieldLabel: 'Start date',
        msgTarget: 'under',
       }
    ],
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
var m = Ext.getCmp('fn');
m.setActiveError("important"); //can change the text
```